# On the convergence / finiteness of $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2e^{an}-1)(2e^{ak}-1)}{(e^{an} + e^{ak} - 1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a > 0$. Consider the sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n \geq 0} = (1 - e^{-an})_{n \geq 0}$. I am looking to prove that

> \begin{equation}
> \sup_{k \geq 0} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(1 - |\lambda_n|^2)(1 - |\lambda_k|^2)}{|1 - \lambda_n \lambda_k |^2} < \infty.
> \end{equation}

I have proceed as follows. Let $k \geq 0$ be fixed. I wanted to prove that the general term of the series is bounded by a geometric or Riemann convergent term in $n$ (so that the series is convergent) and by a bounded term in $k$ (so that the $\sup$ is finite). The general term writes as
\begin{align}
\frac{(1 - |\lambda_n|^2)(1 - |\lambda_k|^2)}{|1 - \lambda_n \lambda_k |^2} &= \frac{(2e^{-an} - e^{-2an})(2e^{-ak} - e^{-2ak})}{|e^{-an} + e^{-ak} - e^{-a(n+k)}|^2} \\
&= \frac{4e^{-a(n+k)}-2e^{-a(n+2k)}-2e^{-a(2n+k)}+e^{-2a(n+k)}}{|e^{-an} + e^{-ak} - e^{-a(n+k)}|^2}.
\end{align}
I tried factoring out more exponentials but in vain. I would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: Hint: $\lambda_n=\mathbb{P}(X\leq n)$ for $X$ a random variable with $X\sim \exp(a)$

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(1 - |\lambda_n|^2)(1 - |\lambda_k|^2)}{|1 - \lambda_n \lambda_k |^2} = (2e^{ak}-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2e^{an}-1}{(e^{an}+e^{ak}-1)^2}$$

Comment: It suffices to get a sharp enough bound on $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2e^{an}-1}{(e^{an}+e^{ak}-1)^2}$ (indexed by $k$), but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Could you give some details on how I could apply this remark?